# Forgot alternative password for encrypted & fingerprint-protected Samsung Galaxy S5: how to reset it?

Tags: lock-screens, encryption, password, fingerprint

So I have an encrypted Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 6.0 and set fingerprints for its lockscreen (fingerprint is set as lockscreen-type for the setting device encryption). Now it seems like I forgot my alternative password - or at least what I tried didn't work.

I can still unencrypt my phone with my password and unlock it with my fingerprints. I didn't need the alternative password so far.
But I'm not sure if it's possible that this could change - e.g. if I happen to make too many false fingerprint-attempts(?) What would you recommend me to do?

I'd prefer changing / resetting the alternative password only if that's possible.
[This page has some info which could be relevant here](http://droidsolve.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-alternative-password-reset-for-fingerprint-scanner/). However that's not for encrypted phones plus I'd like to make sure that I'm not breaking anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it basically solved itself by now: I tried to enter the passphrase many times. Then I used my phone as always and then I shut down. After reboot it showed a screen with an option to change the alternative password. Great!

<sup><strike>I think I might have failed to enter the passphrase correctly because it only accepts 16 characters and iirc the password I had was longer than that.</strike> Actually what I thought was my alternative password was shorter than 16 characters.</sup>

Follow-up question: "[Alternative password has been set as the decryption password](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180532/alternative-password-has-been-set-as-the-encryption-password)"

Another follow-up: now the data on my encrypted SD card has been wiped. Not sure why this was done - the apps still work but the photos on it are just unreadable files. Great.